# How do I get part of a string with a regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex's with python

I have a string which has got a sub-string which I would like to extract from

I have the following pattern:

```
 r = re.compile("(flag{.+[^}]})")
```

and the string is

`Something has gone horribly wrong\n\nflag{Hi!}`

I would like to get hold of just `flag{Hi!}`

I have tried it with:

```
a = re.search(r,string)

a = re.split(r,string)
```

None of the approaches work, if I print `a` I get `None`

How can I get hold of the desired flag.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you print `a` for the re.search variant that you tried, you do not get None, see https://ideone.com/VczxK6 You can simplify the expression to `flag{[^}]+}` and use `print(a.group())`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
str="Something has gone horribly wrong\n\nflag{Hi!}"
r = re.compile("(flag{.+[^}]})")
a = re.search(r,str)
print(a.group())
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

We can directly search the string for matching string.

```
import re
line = 'Something has gone horribly wrong\n\nflag{Hi!}'
r = re.search("(flag{[^}]*})", line)
print(r.group())
    
Output:- 
flag{Hi!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as mentioned in the comments, your output is not `None`. You do get a match, the match you were looking for. You actually get a `Match` object that spans from position `35 -> 44` and matches `flag{Hi!}`. You can use `group()` to get the match represented as a string:

```
>>> a = re.search(r, string)
>>> print(a.group())

"flag{Hi!}"
```

You can also shorten your regex a little bit. There really isn't a need to use `.+` because it becomes redundant when you add `[^}]`, which matches all characters that aren't a closing curly bracket (`}`):

```
"(flag{[^}]+})"
```

You can replace the `+`, which matches *one or more* with `*` which matches *zero or more* if you want to match things like `flag{}` where there are no characters inside the curly brackets.